# A pandas-y way to produce a dataframe from a list that is created using a for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following bit of code:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,2],[3,1],[4,4],[5,4]], columns = ['A','B'])
switch = [[1,3,4],[2,5]]

collect = []
for lists in switch:
    mask = df0.A.isin(lists)
    dat = df0[mask]
    avg=dat.mean().round(2)
    _, p_val = stats.ttest_rel(dat.iloc[0],dat.iloc[1])
    
    collect.append(avg)
    collect.append(p_val.round(2))
```

This produces:

```
[A    2.67
 B    2.33
 dtype: float64,
 0.8,
 A    3.5
 B    3.0
 dtype: float64,
 0.13]
```

but I want:

```
 A     B     C
2.67  2.33  0.8
3.5   3.0   0.13
```

I think my problem is that `collect` is a list that is a mess that includes pd.Series and numbers. What is the most pandas-y way to produce the desired outcome? Or is there a way to improve the way I'm finding the mean and the p-value by not using a loop but using vectorization instead?

Comment: `stats.ttest_rel(dat.iloc[0],dat.iloc[1])` why are you calculating `ttest` for the first two rows of the group only?

Comment: It's supposed to be columns. Clearly I messed up there. I'll edit it.

Comment: see my updated answer for the test on columns.

Comment: I messed up and did t-test on first two rows, which wasn't what I intended. After editing it, my desired output is changes as well, but your output is the one I wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62547424/how-to-create-or-change-the-dimensions-of-an-array-list-using-numpy-or-pandas), we can do a groupby:

```
groups = df0.groupby(pd.Series({x-1:k for k,v in enumerate(switch) for x in v}))

new_df = groups.mean()
new_df['C'] = groups.apply(lambda dat: stats.ttest_rel(dat['A'],dat['B'])[1])
new_df = new_df.round(2)
```

Output:

```
      A     B     C
0  2.67  2.33  0.74
1  3.50  3.00  0.50
```